# CUDA __syncthreads() usage within a warp

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, synchronization

If it was absolutely required for all the threads in a block to be at the same point in the code, do we require the __syncthreads function if the number of threads being launched is equal to the number of threads in a warp?

Note: No extra threads or blocks, just a single warp for the kernel.

Example code:

```
shared _voltatile_ sdata[16];

int index = some_number_between_0_and_15;
sdata[tid] = some_number;
output[tid] = x ^ y ^ z ^ sdata[index];
```

Comment: I think that this is largely an irrelevant question because, if you run `warpSize` (32) threads per block, you are likely to end up with performance that is lower than if you were to run your algorithm on the CPU.

Comment: @RogerDahl I'm not sure I fully understand, you're saying just using 32 threads in warp will always be slower than the CPU for any kernel?

Comment: I didn't say, "always", because one could probably come up with a special set of circumstances for which my statement wouldn't apply. The problem is that if you limit `threads per block` to `warpSize`, you will likely end up with extremely low occupancy (limited by `max blocks per multiprocessor`), which translates into low performance. Also, it just wouldn't make any sense to keep `threads per block` artificially low when you can simply increase `threads per block` and add `__syncthreads()` to get better performance.

Comment: @RogerDahl The thing is, this is actually an encryption algorithm I'm working on, AES w/ CBC. The block size is 16, so I'm only able to figure out how to parallelize the encryption w/ 16 threads. With warp-synchronous programming that Tom mentioned, I may be able to remove all the need for __syncthreads calls and branching.

Comment: Say you were to run a 16-thread kernel on a GTX580, which has 512 SMs. The kernel would be utilizing only 16 / 512 * 100 = 3.125% of the chip. In addition, the threads from a warp do not run continuously. Whenever one warp is waiting for something, the GPU expects to be able to swap in another warp. With 16 threads, there would be no other warps to swap in, dropping your utilization of the GPU to some fraction of the initial 3%. My guess would be maybe 1/5th. So 3.125% / 5 = 0.625%. At such a low utilization, the algorithm would run very slowly on the GPU as compared to the CPU.

Comment: So, as you can see, with an algorithm that is limited to 16 threads, any optimizations you can do are going to be futile. You'll be much better of running it on the CPU.

Comment: @RogerDahl There's a couple of papers I read: http://www.manavski.com/downloads/PID505889.pdf and one presented at HPCA-2012 called "The Case for GPGPU Spatial Multitasking". The both indicate that they retrieved some kind of speedup.My only thought now is that they were actually performing AES encryption in ECB mode instead of CBC mode. Does this mean any attempt at an AES encryption using CBC mode is futile?

Comment: Heh. SO is telling me to avoid extended discussions in comments and wants me to move this to chat. So, if you still have questions after reading this, please go ahead and open a new question. Quote from http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch36.html: *However, because CBC mode needs the ciphertexts of each previous step to process the next step, it is not possible to begin the encryption of a block until its previous block has been encrypted. So we can't hope for parallel processing during the encryption stage of this mode.*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10352/discussion-between-seljuq70-and-roger-dahl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated with more information about using volatile**

Presumably you want all threads to be at the same point since they are reading data written by other threads into shared memory, if you are launching a single warp (in each block) then you know that all threads are executing together. On the face of it this means you can omit the `__syncthreads()`, a practice known as "warp-synchronous programming". However, there are a few things to look out for.

- Remember that a compiler will assume that it can optimise providing the intra-thread semantics remain correct, including delaying stores to memory where the data can be kept in registers. `__syncthreads()` acts as a barrier to this and therefore ensures that the data is written to shared memory before other threads read the data. Using `volatile` causes the compiler to perform the memory write rather than keep in registers, however this has some risks and is more of a hack (meaning I don't know how this will be affected in the future)

  - Technically, you should always use `__syncthreads()` to conform with the CUDA Programming Model
- The warp size is and always has been 32, but you can:

  - At compile time use the special variable `warpSize` in device code (documented in the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation), under "built-in variables", section B.4 in the 4.1 version)
  - At run time use the warpSize field of the cudaDeviceProp struct (documented in the [CUDA Reference Manual](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation))

Note that some of the SDK samples (notably reduction and scan) use this warp-synchronous technique.

Comment: When you say "this applies if the underlying number of cores is less than the warp size", does this mean the C1060 is out of the question? Also, what if I were to launch only 16 threads in the kernel?

Comment: C1060 is still fine. What you're really concerned about is a write to some location followed by a read (or WAR/WAW) and you know that the entire warp will have completed the write before any threads in the warp start the subsequent read. If you launch less than 32 threads the same behaviour applies it's still just a single warp albeit more inefficient. Note that I highly recommend you consider launching larger blocks, with only one warp per block you will find it impossible to cover most latencies.

Comment: I've added an example of similar code I'm working with. The threads will read data written in the previous line of code. Because there is also some bitwise operations done with the shared data, can I just separate out the bitwise operation and place them before read? Will all the threads in warp still be executing the same lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

You still need `__syncthreads()` even if warps are being executed in parallel. The actual execution in hardware may not be parallel because the number of cores within a SM (Stream Multiprocessor) can be less than 32. For example, GT200 architecture has 8 cores in each SM, so you can never be sure all threads are in the same point in the code.

Comment: __syncthreads() can have a performance impact in some intensive codes (e.g. reduction and scan). This issue arises where you want to share data between threads (via shared memory for example). In these cases, where you have a store followed by a load, you know that the entire warp will have executed the store before any threads start the load, even if the number of LS units (number of CUDA cores is not relevant for this) is less than the warp size. There are some other caveats around compiler optimisations!

Comment: -1: The CUDA model guarantees that all threads within a warp are in sync. Quote from the Programming Guide: *Because a warp executes one common instruction at a time, threads within a warp 
are implicitly synchronized and this can sometimes be used to omit 
__syncthreads() for better performance.*

Comment: Section 1.4.8 of the newer Kepler_Tuning_Guide.pdf _depreciates_ taking advantage of Warp-synchronous Programming by eliminating __syncthreads().