# Does anything short of __syncthreads() prevent read-after-write intra-warp shared memory hazards?

Tags: cuda, synchronization, memory-barriers, gpu-shared-memory

I have a warp which writes some data to shared memory - with no overwrites, and soon after reads from shared memory. While there may be other warps in my block, they're not going to touch any part of that shared memory or write to anywhere my warp of interest reads from.

Now, I recall that despite warps executing in lockstep, we are not guaranteed that the shared memory reads following the shared memory writes will return the respective values supposedly written earlier by the warp. (this could theoretically be due to instruction reordering or - as @RobertCrovella points out - the compiler optimizing a shared memory access away)

So, we need to resort to some explicit synchronization. Obviously, the block-level `__syncthreads()` work. This is what [does](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions):

> `__syncthreads()` is used to coordinate communication between the threads of the same block. When some threads within a block access the same addresses in shared or global memory, there are potential read-after-write, write-after-read, or write-after-write hazards for some of these memory accesses. These data hazards can be avoided by synchronizing threads in-between these accesses.

That's too powerful for my needs :

- It applies to **global** memory also, not just **shared** memory.
- It performs **inter-warp** synchronization; I only need **intra-warp**.
- It prevents all types of hazards **R-after-W, W-after-R, W-after-W**; I only need **R-after-W**.
- It works also for cases of multiple threads performing **writes to the same location in shared memory**; in my case **all shared memory writes are disjoint**.

On the other hand, something like `__threadfence_block()` [does not seem to suffice](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions). Is there anything "in-between" those two levels of strength?

**Notes:**

- Related question: [CUDA `__syncthreads()` usage within a warp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205245/cuda-syncthreads-usage-within-a-warp?rq=1).
- If you're going to suggest I use shuffling instead, then, yes, that's sometimes possible - but not if you want to have array access to the data, i.e. dynamically decide which element of the shared data you're going to read. That would probably spill into local memory, which seems scary to me.
- I was thinking maybe `volatile` could be useful to me, but I'm not sure if using it would do what I want.
- If you have an answer that assumes the computer capability is at least XX.YY, that's useful enough.

Comment: For warp-level usage, according to the description in your first paragraph, `volatile` may be of interest.  It's impossible to be sure without a crisp example. Based on your description, I don't see how this is any different than the usage of it in the [classical parallel reduction tutorial](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) (slide 22). The underlying issue is not instruction reordering, but compiler optimization of a shared value into a register

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Wouldn't a compiler optimization like that ensure that I don't need `__syncthreads()` to begin with? And actually - how could it possibly make this optimization when it knows the other threads read from a compile-time-indeterminate shared memory location?

Comment: I don't understand the first question.  Regarding the 2nd question, the compiler doesn't know anything about what other threads are doing.  `volatile` is your way to communicate to the compiler that other threads may be touching this thing that I am looking at.  This is a common misconception about the GPU compiler - that it is somehow multi-thread aware and that its behavior will change based on what may inferentially be happening across threads.  It doesn't work that way.  The programming model has a single thread in view, so does the compiler.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: But surely the compiler works at the _warp_ level, i.e. it decides (and hence knows) what all threads in a warp will be doing. Or is this still a misconception?

Comment: I would call that a misconception.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Puzzling. Oh well. So, does the fragment I wrote up below do what my question asks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand @RobertCrovella correctly, this fragment of code should be safe from the hazard:

```
/* ... */
volatile MyType* ptr = get_some_shared_mem();
ptr[lane::index()] = foo();
auto other_lane_index = bar(); // returns a value within 0..31
auto other_lane_value = ptr[other_lane_index];
/* ... */
```

because of the use of `volatile`. (And assuming `bar()` doesn't mess introduce hazards of its own.)